# Add shapes to JavaFX pane with cartesian coordinates

Tags: java, javafx

If I place any shape (eg Circle) on a javafx pane, the x/y coordinates 0,0 are in the upper left corner. Example circle, presented one forth in the corner:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(0.0, 0.0, 10);
root.getChildren().add(circle);
```

Now I do have a list of objects (circles, lines, arcs etc.) precalculated with coordinates based on the cartesian coordinates (x0, y0 is in the center).

Is there any Pane implementation supporting this coordinate system for shapes? If not, what is the easiest way to transform the coordinates, so the upper circle would be drawn in the center of a given already sized pane?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all your shapes to a `Group` and then translate this group accordantly, like this:

```
Group group = new Group();
Pane pane = new Pane(group);

pane.setPrefWidth(300);
pane.setPrefHeight(300);

group.getChildren().add(new Circle(0, 0, 10));
group.setTranslateX(pane.getPrefWidth() / 2);
group.setTranslateY(pane.getPrefHeight() / 2);
```

[`Group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html):

> Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to
>   all children of that group.

Comment: Also note that if you want to use traditional mathematical coordinates (where `y` increases as you go up, instead of down), you can do `group.setScaleY(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward solution I could think of is a wrapper around JavaFX's `Circle`

```
// Pseudocode
MyCircle(Parent parent, int x, int y, int radius)
{
     parentCenterX = parent.width / 2
     parentCenterY = parent.height / 2

     parent.getChildren().add(new Circle(parentCenterX + x, parentCenterY + y, radius *2))
}
```